# autotools/libtool shared library not installed

Tags: autotools, automake, libtool

Perhaps there is something really basic I don't know, but I'm facing a very weird behaviour: after my libtool shared library was properly built, it is deleted immediately after.

Basically, this `Makefile.am`:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install

lib_LTLIBRARIES =

if BUILD_WIRINGPI_STUB
    lib_LTLIBRARIES += libwiringPiStub.la

    # headers to be installed
    include_HEADERS = \
    src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.h
endif

LIBTOOL_DEPS = @LIBTOOL_DEPS@

# libwiringPiStub.{so,a}
libwiringPiStub_la_LDFLAGS = -rpath '$(libdir)' -version-info $(WIRINGPI_STUB_SOVERSION)
libwiringPiStub_la_SOURCES = src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.c

pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = src/wiringPi-stub/libwiringPiStub.pc
```

produces this build history, which looks ok:

```
% make libwiringPiStub.la
depbase=`echo src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.lo src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.c &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -MT src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.lo -MD -MP -MF src/wiringPi-stub/.deps/wiringPi.Tpo -c src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/wiringPi-stub/.libs/wiringPi.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -rpath '/usr/local/lib' -version-info 1:0:0  -o libwiringPiStub.la  src/wiringPi-stub/wiringPi.lo  -lpthread -lm 
libtool: link: gcc -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libwiringPiStub.1.dylib  src/wiringPi-stub/.libs/wiringPi.o   -lpthread -lm  -g -O2   -install_name  /usr/local/lib/libwiringPiStub.1.dylib -compatibility_version 2 -current_version 2.0 -Wl,-single_module
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libwiringPiStub.dylib" && ln -s "libwiringPiStub.1.dylib" "libwiringPiStub.dylib")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libwiringPiStub.la" && ln -s "../libwiringPiStub.la" "libwiringPiStub.la" )
```

In facts, nothing is installed in my $(libdir) with `make install`, either are the header file in the include dir.

This is the output of the `make install` execution:

```
% make install                       
cd . && /bin/sh ./config.status config.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
 /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c -m 644 src/wiringPi-stub/libwiringPiStub.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
```

In fact, only the .pc file is actually moved in position. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right libdir and includedir?  If you do not override the default prefix or override those specific installation directories when you `configure` the project, then the defaults should be `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, repsectively.

Comment: Does the `make install` command complete successfully?  Can you present its output?

Comment: I've added the output of `make install`, as @JohnBollinger suggestion was unfortunately not successful

Comment: My best guess would be that the `BUILD_WIRINGPI_STUB` conditional is evaluating to false when you `configure` the project.  That would not prevent you from building target `libwiringPiStub.la` by explicitly specifying its name to `make`, as your example shows, but it and its header would not be included in installs.  In that case, you should also see that the library does not get built unless you *do* specifically name it -- that is, it would not be built by just `make` or `make all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be anything inherently wrong with the Automake input file presented, and the fact that target `libwiringPiStub.la` can be built by explicitly requesting that with `make libwiringPiStub.la` tends to support that conclusion.

At the same time, the fact that `make install` completes successfully without even attempting to install the library or the associated header strongly suggests that project configuration resulted in them not being included in the values of the `lib_LTLIBRARIES` and `include_HEADERS` variables.  That would fall out naturally from the `BUILD_WIRINGPI_STUB` Automake conditional evaluating to false at `configure` time, but I see no reason to think that the same would occur if that conditional evaluated to true.  Thus, that's where I expect you to find the problem.

You can verify that the conditional is responsible by looking at the generated `Makefile`.  The body of the conditional will be present in the Makefile either way, but if the conditional evaluates to false then it will be commented out.

Comment: That was really a sniper shot! Problem was in the AM_CONDITIONAL. I was so sure that the issue was due to automake that I didn't check properly the autoconf. In facts, the conditional was evaluate to false due to a missing clause, although the explicit target was making the lib to build correctly anyway (but not to install)